# Disable animation of mat-stepper while in transition

Tags: angular, animation, angular-material2, stepper

Is there any way to disable animation of Angular material's `mat-stepper` control, when we are switching from one step to another ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Angular animations can be disabled by setting the elements property `@.disabled`, see https://angular.io/api/animations/trigger#disable-animations

You can simply put `[@.disabled] = "true"` input to your `mat-stepper`

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [@.disabled]="true" [linear]="isLinear" #stepper>
```

Comment: This causes all inner child animations to be disabled too. As described in the same Angular docs page: "When @.disabled is true, it prevents the @childAnimation trigger from animating, along with any inner animations".